# DetachedInstanceError: SQLAlchemy wants to refresh the DateTime attribute of an expunged instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using a session with `autocommit=True` and `expire_on_commit=False`. I use the session to get an object `A` with a foreign key that points to an object `B`. I then call `session.expunge(a.b); session.expunge(a)`.

Later, when trying to read the value of `b.some_datetime`, SQLAlchemy raises a `DetachedInstanceError`. No attribute has been configured for lazy-loading. The error happens randomly.

How is this possible? I assumed that all scalar attributes would be eagerly loaded and available after the object is expunged.

For what it's worth, the objects get expunged so they can be used in another thread, after all interactions with the database are over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the mapped class's fields had an `onupdate` attribute, which caused it to expire whenever the object is changed.

The solution is to call `session.refresh(myobj)` between the flush and the call to `session.expunge()`.